# Alternative to 'for i in xrange(len(x))'

Tags: python, for-loop, anti-patterns

So I see in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576988/python-specific-antipatterns) the following "bad" snippet, but the only alternatives I have seen involve patching Python.

```
for i in xrange(len(something)):
  workwith = something[i]
  # do things with workwith...
```

What do I do to avoid this "antipattern"?

Answer (score 23):

If you need to know the index in the loop body:

```
for index, workwith in enumerate(something):
    print "element", index, "is", workwith
```

Answer (score 22):

See [Pythonic](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-pythonic)

```
for workwith in something:
    # do things with workwith
```

Comment: fine, unless you want to modify the value. consider 
for workwith in something:
 workwith += 1

Comment: @vartec: that’s true, but given Alam question he does not.

Comment: @vartec I know this is an old question, but to clarify - if you need to modify values, still don't loop by index, that's what list comprehensions are for.

Answer (score 12):

As there are [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578677/alternative-to-for-i-in-xrangelenx/578694#578694) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578677/alternative-to-for-i-in-xrangelenx/578685#578685) to question that are perfectly valid (with an assumption each) and author of the question didn't inform us about the destiny of index, the valid answer should read:

> If you [do not need index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578677/alternative-to-for-i-in-xrangelenx/578685#578685) at all:
>
> ```
> for workwith in something:
>     print "element", workwith
> ```
>
> If you [need index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578677/alternative-to-for-i-in-xrangelenx/578694#578694):
>
> ```
> for index, workwith in enumerate(something):
>     print "element", index, "is", workwith
> ```

If my answer is not appropriate, comment please, and I'll delete it :)

Comment: +1: No, your answer is most appropriate, and the most complete, actually.

Answer (score 0):

for example:

```
[workwith(i) for i in something]
```

Comment: 'something' is a collection of objects. From the original, it does not appear that 'something' is necessarily integers nor that 'workwith' is a collection at all. 'workwith' appears to be a temporary variable for workign with 'something'.

Answer (score -3):

What is `x`? If its a sequence or iterator or string then

```
for i in x:
    workwith = i
```

will work fine.

Comment: SilentGhost's answer is better :-)

Comment: I can't think of any situation in which this is the best answer. It appears to be an inferior version of kmkaplan's answer. (I realize it was posted before kmkaplan, but it *is* possible to delete one's answer, once an unambiguously superior one has been proposed.) Nevertheless, I didn't put -1 on it, since it has been knocked down enough by others.